# Why I get AMQ7077 even after turning security in WebSphere MQ off?

Tags: shell, ibm-mq, redhat

In Windows7 when I set `MQSNOAUT=yes` everything is ok and I can do whatever I want in WebSphere MQ. But in RedHat even after setting `MQSNOAUT` to `yes` I'm getting this error:

```
[root@RHEL6-135 bin]$ ll crtmqm  
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mqm mqm 41822 Oct 22  2015 crtmqm  
[root@RHEL6-135 bin]$ crtmqm testqm  
AMQ7077: You are not authorized to perform the requested operation.  
[root@RHEL6-135 bin]$
```

Using `mqm` user I can create queue manager but cannot start it:

```
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$ crtmqm testqm  
WebSphere MQ queue manager created.  
Directory '/var/mqm/qmgrs/testqm' created.  
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.  
Creating or replacing default objects for queue manager 'testqm'.  
Default objects statistics : 79 created. 0 replaced. 0 failed.  
Completing setup.  
Setup completed.  
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$ strmqm testqm  
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'testqm' starting.  
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.  
5 log records accessed on queue manager 'testqm' during the log replay phase.  
Log replay for queue manager 'testqm' complete.  
Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'testqm'.  
The queue manager ended for reason 545284129, ''.  
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$
```

Unfortunately, there is no useful information in these log files:

/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG:

```
----- amqxfdcx.c : 888 --------------------------------------------------------  
03/14/2017 10:00:16 AM - Process(15859.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmur0)  
                    Host(RHEL6-135) Installation(Installation1)  
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4)  
AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.  

EXPLANATION:  
An internal error has occurred with identifier 2080520F.  This message is  
issued in association with other messages.  
ACTION:  
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem  
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support  
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support  
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a  
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your  
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been  
resolved.  
...  
repeated 27 times!
```

/var/mqm/qmgrs/testqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG:

```
03/14/2017 10:00:16 AM - Process(15840.4) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)  
                    Host(RHEL6-135) Installation(Installation1)  
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(testqm)  

AMQ5051: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has started.  

EXPLANATION:  
The critical utility task manager has started the LOGGER-IO task. This task has  
now started 1 times.  
ACTION:  
None.  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  ....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
03/14/2017 10:00:16 AM - Process(15859.6) User(mqm) Program(amqzmur0)  
                    Host(RHEL6-135) Installation(Installation1)   
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(testqm)  

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'DEFERRED_DELIVERY' has started.  

EXPLANATION:  
The restartable utility task manager has started the DEFERRED_DELIVERY task.  
This task has now started 1 times.  
ACTION:  
None.  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `mqm` user is `sudoer` and the following is a part of my /etc/group file:

```
root:x:0:root, mqm, bin
adm:x:4:root,adm,daemon, mqm, mquser
mqm:x:500:root, mqm
mquser:x:502:mqm
```

... regardless all these, I think having `MQSNOAUT` variable that is set to `yes` should be enough to work with WebShpere MQ using any user. Maybe something related to RedHat caused the problem.

BTW, searching for `The queue manager ended for reason 545284129, ''.`, I couldn't find any solution.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Having done `chmod -R 6550` on `/opt/mqm/bin`, now I can start queue managers and create queue, channel, ... using IBM MQ's command line binaries. For more convenient, however, still I can't use MQ Explorer, because when I run `MQExplorer` I get the following error:

```
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$ MQExplorer
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display:
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display:
MQExplorer:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/var/mqm/IBM/WebSphereMQ/workspace-Installation1/.metadata/.log.
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$
```

Running it with `sudo` I get this error:

```
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$ sudo MQExplorer
[sudo] password for mqm:
/opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(process:4451): Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running setuid or setgid.
This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helper
program instead. For further details, see:

    http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html

Refusing to initialize GTK+.
[mqm@RHEL6-135 bin]$
```

and the `/var/mqm/IBM/WebSphereMQ/workspace-Installation1/.metadata/.log` is as follows:

```
!SESSION 2017-03-15 16:41:52.369 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.7 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255653 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20150623_94888.01
GC   - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150630_255653
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-15 16:41:54.516
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:925)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.start(RcpApplication.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

The log/stacktrace looks like a `catch-all` exception handling. I didn't yet completely digged into this error but maybe it is also caused by some permission problems. For example, maybe some authorization errors are raised when MQExplorer tries to load it's components from mqm's sub-directories! However, running `chmod -R 6550` on some related paths didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did my suggestions help to resolve your issue?  Let me know if you need me to provide more information.

Comment: @JoshMc Yeah, that resolved my problem. Many thanks for your help :) I've updated the question, take a look at it, please, and let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Not all files have 6550 permissions under /opt/mqm.  I think it is best to uninstall and reinstall to get the proper permissions.  If you still have the MQ Explorer problem it is best to move that to a new question.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `MQSNOAUT=ANYVALUE` only turns off MQ OAM if it is set at the time the queue manager is created.  It results a few lines being omitted from the qm.ini file for the queue manager you create while it is set.

If OAM is turned off it means only that any user connecting to the queue manager will have full authority.

The queue manager itself on Unix still needs to run under the mqm userid.

I noted that you showed the following permissions on the crtmqm binary:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mqm mqm
```

This is not correct, the MQ install on Unix has many of the files with setuid permission because the permissions on the files that are created under `/var/mqm/qmgrs`, `/var/mqm/log`, `/var/mqm/sockets` are very important.  From the research I did the 545284129 and 2080520F errors are related to file permissions.  I would suggest you reset the permissions back to what they previously were, if you do not know then I would suggest you remove the IBM MQ software and reinstall.  For reference below is the normal permissions on the crtmqm binary:

```
-r-sr-s--- 1 mqm mqm
```

Once the IBM MQ binary permissions are corrected I would suggest that you use `dltmqm` to delete your queue manager and ensure that nothing remains related to that queue manager name under `/var/mqm/qmgrs`, `/var/mqm/log`, `/var/mqm/sockets`, and in the `/var/mqm/mqs.ini` file.

Once it is cleaned up, create it again as the mqm user and try starting it.

I would suggest that you try not to disable security and instead set things up with proper permissions.  Even if this is a development environment, it is much better to get things working with security enabled.  When you develop with security disabled you end up needing to troubleshoot why things are not working later when security is turned on in a real environment.

Take a look at my answer to question "[Provide anonymous access to IBM WebSphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373211/provide-anonymous-access-to-ibm-websphere-mq/42373625#42373625)" for some more information on how to keep security enabled as well as disabling things if you want to continue down that path.

Comment: The fact is that after installing WebSphere MQ, I ran `chmod -R 777` on the mqm installation path! because I had got authorization error when I ran `crtmqm` with `root` user. In troubleshooting process I had seen somewhere that the permission must be `r-sr-s---` or `(6550)oct` but since I thought that the `x` is more general than the `s (set(u|g|o)id)`, I ignored it. After reading some materials about the `s`, now I know it is basically different from `x` ... maybe it can be said it provides bottom-up security!